# Wrong Solution if Memoization is added to Recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic, c++14, memoization

I have created a DP program but the problem is that I get correct answers when I don't use memoization. As soon as I introduce memoization, I start getting the wrong answers for some problems

Here is the code in C++ 14 with memoization turned off (By commenting)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;
int max_Number_of_turns;
int dp[9999][1000];
int changeTheDigit(int n, int d) {
    int rem = n % (int) (pow(10, 4 - d));
    n /= (pow(10, 4 - d));
    int x = n % 10;
    n /= 10;
    if (x == 9) x = 0;
    else x = x + 1;
    n = n * (10) + x;
    n = n * (pow(10, 4 - d)) + rem;
    return n;
}

int minMax(int n, int t) {
    int ans =0;
    //if(dp[n][t]>=0) { return dp[n][t];}
    if (t > max_Number_of_turns) return n;

    int N;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        N = changeTheDigit(n, i + 1);
        if (t % 2 == 0) {
            //Manish chance
            if(ans==0) ans=minMax(N, t+1);
            else ans = min(ans, minMax(N, t + 1));
        } else {
            //Nitish Chance
            ans = max(ans, minMax(N, t + 1));
        }
    }
    //cout << ans << endl;
    dp[n][t]=ans;
    return ans;
}

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int T, N, M;
    cin >> T;
    while (T--) {
        cin >> N >> M;
        max_Number_of_turns=M;
        for(int i=0;i<9999;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<1000;j++)
                dp[i][j]=-1;
        if(minMax(N,1)>N){
            cout << "Nitish" << endl;
        }
        else{
            cout << "Manish" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Turn the memoization comment on (i.e. remove the comments from this line)

```
if(dp[n][t]>=0) { return dp[n][t];}
```

and my code will give wrong answers to some problems
For example, let us consider the input

```
1
4569 12
```

Original Correct Solution is Manish
But If I turn on memoization, My solution is Nitish

Can you suggest me that what am I doing wrong here

Also, a fun fact is that, if the change the DP code from

```
if(dp[n][t]>=0) { return dp[n][t];}
```

to

```
if(dp[n][t]>0) { return dp[n][t];}
```

Then everything is fine

Comment: "*As soon as I introduce DP, I start getting the wrong answers for some problems*" - maybe you implemented it incorrectly?

Comment: Why not take that code and use your debugger?  Is this code from one of those "online coding" sites, where you are using their embedded compiler, instead of getting your own compiler so you can debug your code?  If so, get a compiler, take your code, compile it, *debug it*.  You have the test case and the output it produces -- no need for us to do the debugging work for you.

Comment: The program you show [prints "Manish"](http://rextester.com/JDW45809) with or without that line. To the extent there is a problem, it must lie elsewhere.  By the way, the technique you try to use is called [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization); it has nothing to do with dynamic programming.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Sorry, I gave the wrong set of input. Try it for the new input that I have given in the edited question and you will get wrong solution with memoization turned on

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have tried this code on both online compilers and compiler on my PC.

Comment: @VishalSingh ok, so you tried the code on your compiler.  Have you debugged your code?  If not, please read: [I downvoted because...](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: `minMax` is occasionally called with `n >= 9999`, whereupon `dp` is accessed out of bounds and the program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: @VishalSingh And to prove what Igor Tandetnik is stating, [see this](https://www.ideone.com/Grx45t).  Usage of `std::vector` and `at()` shows you are going out-of-bounds.  This shows that online coding sites do not teach *how* to diagnose problems, or even write C++ code where problems can be diagnosed easily.  If you didn't use raw arrays and instead used `std::vector`, you would have had a chance to find the issue yourself easily.

Comment: I really don't understand why it runs occasionally for a number greater than 9999 because changeTheDigit will never return a number greater than 9999. Anyway, why the programs runs perfectly if I change if(dp[n][t]>=0) { return dp[n][t];} to if(dp[n][t]>0) { return dp[n][t];}

Comment: @VishalSingh [No it doesn't run at all](https://www.ideone.com/XBrhTm).  The issue is that you're using raw arrays, where if you go out-of-bounds, it isn't guaranteed anything "bad" will happen, but you will never know you went out-of-bounds.  If you used `std::vector`, you are *guaranteed* that an exception will be thrown if you access the elements out-of-bounds using `at()` instead of `[]`.  See the difference when you actually know how to write good C++ code, or at least know how to write code that reveals bugs?  Errors just reveal themselves.  Online coding sites do not stress this.

Comment: The folks above have already found your bug. One way to debug this would be to use the "memo" as a cross-check on the calculated value - i.e.don't quit early, bvt if you think you have already calculated the value check at the end that you got the same answer. This lets you focus on the broken issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the values for `n` and/or `t` are not checked and so could cause out-of-bounds issues with the array. You can see that if you insert the following at the start of your `minMax` function:

```
if (n < 0 || n >= 9999) cout << "n invalid at " << n << '\n';
if (t < 0 || t >= 1000) cout << "t invalid at " << t << '\n';
```

Running that with your sample input gives warnings before outputting the result:

```
n invalid at 9999
n invalid at 9999
n invalid at 9999
```

To fix this, you can just ensure you only use memoisation when you have enough storage for it, first when *checking* the value:

```
if (n >= 0 && n < 9999 && t >= 0 && t < 1000 && dp[n][t] >= 0)
    return dp[n][t];
```

and, second, when *storing* the value:

```
if (n >= 0 && n < 9999 && t >= 0 && t < 1000)
    dp[n][t] = ans;
```